# How to Pass multiple arguments with values to executable via Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am trying to run a windows executable via python3 and have below code snippet. The arguments can be of the form `key-value` pair but its possible that few arguments may not have value like `arg1` below. `arg2` needs to have a value which is passed as creating `arg2` variable below. The data.filepath needs to be used to construct arg2

```
 # data.filepath resolves to \\server1\data\inputs\filename.txt
 arg2 = "--arg2 {}".format(data.filepath)  
child = subprocess.Popen([output_path, "--arg1", arg2, "--arg3 val3", "--arg4 val4"],
                         shell=False, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
child.communicate()[0]
rc = child.returncode
```

But seems that i am not following correct syntax and getting error as below

```
Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)
Dynamic exception type: class boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<struct boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<class boost::program_options::unknown_option> >
std::exception::what: unrecognised option '--arg2 \\server1\data\inputs\filename.txt'
```

Please let me know the right syntax in python to pass arguments to executables properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the program you are running expects to receive an argument and its value as separate strings (which makes a lot of sense). You can do something like

```
if phase_of_moon() == 'waxing gibbous':
    arg2 = ['--arg2', data.filepath]
else:
    arg2 = []
x = Popen([output_path, '--arg1', *arg2, '--arg3', val3])
```

using [iterable unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/) to expand `arg2`.